# Как получить el как dom элемент (Vue js?)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Можно ли обратиться к элементу напрямую (типо this.el), а не городить, как в примере ниже?

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#sidebar',
        data: {
            leftCoordinate: document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetTop,
            topCoordinate: document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetLeft,
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так: this.$root.$el